# QGIS polygon centriods - How are they created?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, centroids

I have been using QGIS to analyses spatial data and I created polygon centroids with the vector geometry tools. Now for a report I have to explain how these centroids were created. I have not been able to find an algorithm or an explanation of how QGIS creates centroids, can anyone help?

Comment: You may be able to assume that they use a standard formula, such as can be seen at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon). (I'm not advocating using Wikipedia exclusively as a source of content for a report, but it's often a reasonable starting point.)

Answer (score 4):

For general centroid creation, QGIS [QgsGeometry](http://qgis.org/api/2.4/classQgsGeometry.html) functions wrap respective calls to the underlying [GEOS library](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/):

- [`QgsGeometry * QgsGeometry::centroid()`](http://qgis.org/api/2.4/classQgsGeometry.html#ab6724dc35795363a9e1e9bb2ea459612) ([definition](http://qgis.org/api/2.4/qgsgeometry_8cpp_source.html#l05729)) calls [`GEOSGetCentroid`](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1Centroid.html) ([definition](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/3.4.2/src/algorithm/CentroidArea.cpp))
- [`QgsGeometry * QgsGeometry::pointOnSurface()`](http://qgis.org/api/2.4/classQgsGeometry.html#a95be2bd49d86a455e60411032e4bc8fb) ([definition](http://qgis.org/api/2.4/qgsgeometry_8cpp_source.html#l05744)) calls [`GEOSPointOnSurface`](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1InteriorPointArea.html) ([definition](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/3.4.2/src/algorithm/InteriorPointArea.cpp))

The `pointOnSurface()` function is new for QGIS 2.4 and allows a workaround for when `GEOSGetCentroid` returns a centroid that lies outside the polygon's surface, e.g. as with a 'C'-shaped geometry. Such a result can make the centroid actually appear on the surface of an adjacent polygon.

*Note: `GEOSPointOnSurface` does not 'weight' the point to the center of the polygon's area.*

You can see how the `pointOnSurface()` function is used to provide such a fix [with this commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/770cfe0a43827c778200d7fbaa514d3cd092d379#diff-e10ef50caabc68f07c47727127e85dc7) for symbology.

Comment: I am certainly going to be trying this pointOnSurface() function out, another thing I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Centroid computation in Qgis are based on the GEOS library. I can then refer you to the the documentation of GEOS itself (http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1algorithm_1_1Centroid.html) where you can find the basic principle for polygon centroid computation:

> Based on the usual algorithm for calculating the centroid as a
>   weighted sum of the centroids of a decomposition of the area into
>   (possibly overlapping) triangles. The algorithm has been extended to
>   handle holes and multi-polygons. See
>   http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/ for further details
>   of the basic approach.

Comment: Very helpful both for answering my question, but also as resource.